# Example of Configuration for <httpErrors>

Tags: asp.net, iis-7, web-config

I have a Web Application in Asp.Net 4 running locally on IIS 7.
I need display a Custom Page (404) and an 500 instead for the defaults page for IIS.
Using this httpErrors in Web.Config

```
<system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>
```

My Site is in

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\
```

My Custom Error page in:

```
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\ErrorPages\404.htm
C:\inetpub\wwwroot\mysite\ErrorPages\505.htm
```

I do not understand how it works. COuld you please provide me a sample of code?

Thanks

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I solved my problem with this.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <remove statusCode="500" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
    <error statusCode="500" path="/500.aspx" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL" />
  </httpErrors>
```

This needs to go in `Web.config`, under `<configuration>` > `<system.webServer>`

e.g.

```
<configuration>
    <system.webServer>
        <httpErrors ...>
            // define errors in here ...
        </httpErrors>
    </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

Comment: You can omit the `prefixLanguageFilePath=""`.

Comment: Suggestion: include the parent elements so readers can see this goes inside `<configuration><system.webServer>`

Answer (score 6):

Here is an example, hope it helps

```
<system.web>
<customErrors mode="RemoteOnly" defaultRedirect="default.aspx">
<error statusCode="404" redirect="~/ErrorPages/404.htm"/>
<error statusCode="500" redirect="~/ErrorPages/505.htm"/>
</customErrors>
</system.web>
```

**Edit for comments:** Here's the example I think you need

```
<configuration>
   <system.webServer>
      <httpErrors errorMode="DetailedLocalOnly" defaultResponseMode="File" >
         <remove statusCode="500" />
         <error statusCode="500"
            prefixLanguageFilePath="C:\Contoso\Content\errors"
            path="500.htm" />
       </httpErrors>
   </system.webServer>
</configuration>
```

http://www.iis.net/ConfigReference/system.webServer/httpErrors/error

Comment: thanks this is working for asp.net but on my server i need the configuration for even static content

Comment: I'm sorry, I don't understand. Could you explain?

Comment: for my understanding your code works if I require a page that do not exist (with extension .aspx) ex: foo.aspx where foo.aspx does not exist on the server. I need instead work with <system.webServer>
    <httpErrors>.... do you have any examples?