# How to add a default error page using httpErrors

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, iis, custom-error-pages

i have successfully added a custom 404 page. what I want to do is to create another custom error page that is displayed when there is any error other than 404. e.g. 500, 403 etc.

this is what I have right now in webconfig

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Replace">
      <remove statusCode="404" subStatusCode="-1" />
      <error statusCode="404" path="/404.aspx" responseMode="ExecuteURL"/>
    </httpErrors>
```

Comment: checkout this link here maybe this gone help you  http://www.iis.net/configreference/system.webserver/httperrors/error

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Oh, my. I cannot believe I could not find a proper answer for this simple question! Nevertheless, after 2 hours of reading the docs and debugging, I found it.

```
<httpErrors errorMode="Custom" existingResponse="Auto" defaultResponseMode="ExecuteURL" defaultPath="/App/Error"> <!-- Do not include ~, this was my issue all long -->
  <clear/> <!-- so that IIS provided error pages are skipped -->
  <!-- add those which you like to provide a view of yours -->
  <error path="/App/Http404" responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="404"/>
  <error path="/App/Http503" responseMode="ExecuteURL" statusCode="503"/>
</httpErrors>
```

Beaware that `<httpErrors>` configures IIS, while `<customErrors>` configures ASP.NET and some older versions of IIS (<=6?).

Comment: Unfortunately, defaultPath attribute of httpErrors seems to be locked down in Azure.

Comment: @Ghasan, what if we host application in azure or aws will this work ?

Comment: @RakeshSadhula, I don't have experience with either. But judging from Triynko comment, it might not be working on Azure.

Comment: What saved me was the comment that the tag Custom errors works for asp.net, most google results told me to get rid of it.

Comment: @OsiasJota <customerrors> is for IIS6< <httpErrors> is for IIS7+ (all the way until IIS10 so far). <httpErrors> overrides <customErrors>. <customErrors> cannot deal with some errors such as 500 and 403. <httpErrors> operates at IIS level, <customErrors> runs at application level.

Answer (score -1):

You can use customErrors in webconfig :

```
<customErrors mode="On" defaultRedirect="~/DefaultError.aspx?msg=SomeMessage">
  <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/PageNotFound.html"/>
  <error statusCode="403" redirect="~/AccessDenied.html"/>
</customErrors>
```

Comment: I tried customErrors but I couldn't get it to work. so switched to httpErrors.

Comment: so you can see this [http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729351/2114572](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7729351/2114572)