# The configuration section 'httpErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration

Tags: iis, asp.net-web-api, web-config, custom-error-pages

I am trying to configure a custom error page for the 403 Forbidden response in my WebApi application by adapting [Example of Configuration for <httpErrors>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7729261/example-of-configuration-for-httperrors). I added `<httpErrors>` to my Web.config but I'm getting `HTTP Error 500.19` and `The configuration section 'httpErrors' cannot be read because it is missing a section declaration`.

How can I fix it?

---

My code:

```
<system.web>
  ....
  <httpErrors errorMode="Custom">
    <remove statusCode="403" subStatusCode='-1' />
    <error statusCode="403" path="/forbidden.html" prefixLanguageFilePath="" responseMode="ExecuteURL"  />
  </httpErrors>
</system.web>
```

Screenshot of the error:

[image]

Comment: `httpErrors` belongs to `system.webServer`, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Comment: Thanks, that fixed it!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Copied from the comment.

Such error messages are clear, which requires you to go to IIS reference documentation to learn the actual sections.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httperrors/

Then it is obvious that `httpErrors` is a section under `system.webServer`, not `system.web`.