# IIS show different custom error pages for same status code depending on reason phrase

Tags: iis, custom-error-pages

I need to show different custom error pages depending on the error text/reason phrase, not just the status code.

For example, if I have this code:

```
        if (id == 1)
        {
            throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) {ReasonPhrase = "foo"} );
        }
        throw new HttpResponseException(new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Forbidden) { ReasonPhrase = "bar" });
```

I would like IIS to return one kind of custom page for `403 foo` and another for `403 bar`. This is because I need to customize the errors returned by a Request Interceptor for which we don't have the source code.

Ideally we could specify a ReasonPhrase regex in addition to the status code in [`<httpErrors>`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54291482/the-configuration-section-httperrors-cannot-be-read-because-it-is-missing-a-se).

If there is no builtin way in IIS, I would probably try to make another Request Interceptor and chain it in front so it can modify the responses and serve the custom error pages.

Comment: Unless you write your own IIS extensions, it won't be this smart, or most people do not have such a requirement.

Comment: I didn't quite understand that, what won't be smart?

Comment: A general system can only cover common features, and leave extension API for customization. Your scenario is in a field that customization is necessary.

Comment: You mean I should write a request interceptor?